# Plone Theming Error

Tags: python, plone

Plone is throwing me the following error on the home page when I installed this theme called "Keep it Simple"

The error is: `error while rendering plone.personal_bar`

Its showing on the home page of the site, I'm not able to see the admin section of the site anymore. Relvant Error Logs are:

[http://pastie.org/private/uqsxrtytoxkttfakek2oq](http://pastie.org/private/ncd4ygbpxxqat1pn2okg)

http://pastie.org/private/ncd4ygbpxxqat1pn2okg

Answer (score 2):

The error I get with **Plone 4.3.3** and **plonetheme.keepitsimple 1.1a3** is:

﻿

```
2014-06-09 07:37:00 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.personal_bar fails: user.gif
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/plone.app.viewletmanager-2.0.5-py2.7.egg/plone/app/viewletmanager/manager.py", line 105, in render
    html.append(viewlet.render())
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/plone.app.layout-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py", line 50, in render
    return self.index()
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Products/Five/browser/pagetemplatefile.py", line 125, in __call__
    return self.im_func(im_self, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Products/Five/browser/pagetemplatefile.py", line 59, in __call__
    sourceAnnotations=getattr(debug_flags, 'sourceAnnotations', 0),
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.pagetemplate-3.6.3-py2.7.egg/zope/pagetemplate/pagetemplate.py", line 132, in pt_render
    strictinsert=0, sourceAnnotations=sourceAnnotations
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.pagetemplate-3.6.3-py2.7.egg/zope/pagetemplate/pagetemplate.py", line 240, in __call__
    interpreter()
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 271, in __call__
    self.interpret(self.program)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 852, in do_condition
    self.interpret(block)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 852, in do_condition
    self.interpret(block)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 531, in do_optTag_tal
    self.no_tag(stuff[-2], stuff[-1])
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 513, in no_tag
    self.interpret(program)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 343, in interpret
    handlers[opcode](self, args)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tal-3.5.2-py2.7.egg/zope/tal/talinterpreter.py", line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
    structure = self.engine.evaluateStructure(expr)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 218, in evaluateStructure
    text = super(ZopeContext, self).evaluateStructure(expr)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tales-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/tales.py", line 696, in evaluate
    return expression(self)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tales-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/expressions.py", line 217, in __call__
    return self._eval(econtext)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 147, in _eval
    ob = self._subexprs[-1](econtext)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/zope.tales-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/zope/tales/expressions.py", line 124, in _eval
    ob = self._traverser(ob, element, econtext)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Products/PageTemplates/Expressions.py", line 94, in trustedBoboAwareZopeTraverse
    object = object.unrestrictedTraverse(name)
  File "/Users/alexclark/Developer/eggs-directory/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/OFS/Traversable.py", line 285, in unrestrictedTraverse
    raise e
AttributeError: user.gif
```

which you can fix by copying the deprecated `user.gif` from `portal_skins/plone_deprecated` to `portal_skins/custom` via the **Customize** button:

[image]

[image]